# Errors in PhotoHunt sample app

Tags: google-plus

I followed the following documentation to see demo for the PhotoHunt app.
https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/java

When I run the application, I get the following in the web-browser

```
    HTTP ERROR: 503

    Problem accessing /. Reason:

    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
 Powered by Jetty://
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate getters and setters for the variables declared. Could run the application when these are generated.